How to solve $\left\lfloor \frac{m+n-1}d\right \rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{m-1}d\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}d\right\rfloor$?
I'm having trouble solving the following diophantine equation, as I don't know how to deal with the floor function:
$$\left\lfloor \frac{m+n-1}d\right \rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{m-1}d\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}d\right\rfloor$$
where $m, n, d \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.
Edit:
I noticed that when $1<m+n \leq d$, the equation is satisfied, so I was actually trying to prove or disprove if there were solutions when $m+n>d$. I got tunnel vision, and "forgot" about the Division Theorem, even though I got here by using it. Thanks for the answers. They were very insightful.
I'll try better next time I post.

$m = da + b, ~n = df + g ~: a,f \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~b,g \in {0,1,2,\cdots,d-1}.$

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

@AnneBauval Thanks for those links. I'll keep them in mind for the next time.

Note that $d\left\lfloor \frac n d \right\rfloor = n - \text{rem}(n, d)$.  If we substitute $a = m-1, b = n-1$ and multiply through by $d$, we can rewrite the equation as
$$\text{rem}(a + b + 1, d) = \text{rem}(a, d) + \text{rem}(b, d) + 1$$
which is true if and only if the right side is $< d$.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
